# How do I get the get list of connections from processContext in NiFi 1.11.4

Tags: apache-nifi

Our production instance of NiFi is version 1.8.0. We have a custom processor that continually looks at it's downstream connections in order to route flow files based on the connection's queue size.

Here is the salient snippet of how we do this . . .

```
String processorId = this.getIdentifier();

ProcessorGroupStatus processGroupStatus = ((EventAccess) getControllerService()).getContollerStatus();
Collection<ConnectionStatus> groupConnections = processGroupStatus.getConnectionStatus();
ArrayList connections = new ArrayList<>(groupConnections);

for (Object processorConnection : connections) {

    ConnectionStatus connection = (ConnectionStatus) processorConnection;
    if(connection.getSourceId().equals(processorId){

        //do stuff with connection.getQueuedCount() & connection.getQueuedBytes()
        break;
    }
}
```

Everything has been working as expected for the last couple of years. However, upgrading our NiFi instance to version 1.11.4 has broken this approach. The exception thrown is:

```
class org.apache.nifi.contoller.serviceStandardContollerServiceProvider cannot be cast to class org.apache.nifi.reporting.EventAccess
```

Is there another way to retrieve connections from processContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that may be more upwardly compatible (and easier to maintain) than a custom Java processor would be to use the *ExecuteGroovyScript* processor.

The Groovy script in this case would look something like:

```java
ff = session.get()
if (ff) {
  me = context.procNode
  processorId = me.identifier
  connections = me.processGroup.connections

  connections.each { connection ->
    if(connection.source.identifier.equals(processorId)) {
      ff[connection.identifier] = "I am the source " +
         "[" + connection.flowFileQueue.size().objectCount + "]" +
         "[" + connection.flowFileQueue.size().byteCount + "]"
    }
    else {
      ff[connection.identifier] = "I am NOT the source; my name is [" + connection.name + "]"
    }
  }

  REL_SUCCESS << ff
}
```

To find out what is available to the Groovy script, I use a combination of the NiFi JavaDocs (https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/1.12.0/index.html) and the Github code for NiFi (https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/c396927299586b896df4ebc745793b4c451f3898/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi).

As a side note, we converted our custom Java processors to Groovy script, because of an upgrade incompatibility when going *to* (ironically) 1.8.0. We have not had an issue with NiFi upgrades since then, and are currently running v 1.11.4.

Comment: My snippet is one piece of a larger custom processor. But I peeled out this functionality and adapted it to your groovy script sample. The end product does what I need it to do.
But it would still be preferable in our case to figure out how to get ProcessorGroupStatus from processContext.